# What does the operator $() mean in Docker

Tags: linux, shell, docker

This is probably a pretty straight forward answer. I have Googled this in relation to the following command for Docker:

`docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)`

I looked for the operator in Go, Docker and Linux. It's obvious from the context it's some kind of pipe to the `rm` command but I'd love to know if it truly is some sort of pipe and why it isn't just `docker rm | docker ps -a -q`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$()` operator isn't a docker operator, it's a bash operator which returns the output of the command between the parenthesis. So what you're doing here is running `docker ps -a -q` and then plugging the output of that command to `docker run <output substituted here>`.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't look up bash.

Comment: Thanks for editing the tags as well. Came back to do that and saw it was already done :-)